# How to solve my Dataframe and Writing to Excel File code?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, max

For my studies project, I would like to create a data frame and Excel File from my arbitrage bot.
But I have issue inside the code but I don't understand why.

```
MAX_OUTCOMES = max([event.num_outcomes for event in arbitrage_events])
ARBITRAGE_EVENTS_COUNT = len(arbitrage_events)

my_columns = ['ID', 'Sport Key', 'Expected Earnings'] + list(np.array([[f'Bookmaker #{outcome}', f'Name #{outcome}', f'Odds #{outcome}', f'Amount to Buy #{outcome}'] for outcome in range(1, MAX_OUTCOMES + 1)]).flatten())
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_columns)
```

And when I run it on colab.google this happen.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-635cefa5bb24> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 MAX_OUTCOMES = max([event.num_outcomes for event in arbitrage_events])
      2 ARBITRAGE_EVENTS_COUNT = len(arbitrage_events)
      3 
      4 my_columns = ['ID', 'Sport Key', 'Expected Earnings'] + list(np.array([[f'Bookmaker #{outcome}', f'Name #{outcome}', f'Odds #{outcome}', f'Amount to Buy #{outcome}'] for outcome in range(1, MAX_OUTCOMES + 1)]).flatten())
      5 dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_columns)

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

For my studies project, I would like to create a data frame and Excel File from my arbitrage bot. But I have issue inside the code but I don't understand why.

Comment: According to the error message, your variable `arbitrage_events` is empty. Meaning the list has length of 0. If you provide a minimal working example it's easier to know for sure. In the meantime take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).